# PHP YouTube Api V3 MaxResults Not Working

Tags: php, linux, api, youtube, google-api-php-client

I just implemented Google Api into my app using the YouTube service to get youtube videos. It works as expected as far as getting the results but for some reason MAXRESULTS is not working. It will display results but if i set for example 15 then it shows a endless number of results on the page.

```
    <?php
    //Load The Google Api Client
    //Added Google Api Support 01/21/2016
    set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.'vendor/google/apiclient/src');


    //=================================================================================
    //START GOOGLE API INTEGRATION
    //=================================================================================
    $htmlBody = <<<END
    <form method="GET">
    <div>
    Search For YouTube Video<br>
    <input type="search" id="q" name="q" placeholder="SEARCH" size="30">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    END;

    if ( $_GET['q'] ) 
    {
    require_once 'Google/Client.php';
    require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';


    $DEVELOPER_KEY = 'REMOVED FOR OBVIOUS REASONS';

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setDeveloperKey($DEVELOPER_KEY);

  // Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
  $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

  try {
    // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
    // query term.
    $searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
      'q' => $_GET['q'],
      'maxResults' => 15,
      'type' => 'video',
    ));

    $videos = '';

    // Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
    // matching videos.
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $searchResult) 
    {
      switch ($searchResult['id']['kind']) 
      {
        case 'youtube#video':
          $videotitle = $searchResult['snippet']['title'];  
          $videoid = $searchResult['id']['videoId'];

          $videoembed = '<iframe width="150" height="150" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$videoid.'?autoplay=0&hd=1&vq=hd720" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';  
          $htmloutput .= '
          <table width="50%" align="center">
          <tr>
            <th colspan="2">'.$i.'. '.$videotitle.'</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="40%">'.$videoembed.'</td>
            <td width="60%" align="center">
                <form action="index.php" method="post" id="conversionForm">
                    <input type="hidden" name="youtubeURL" value="'.$videoid.'">    
                    <input type="hidden" value="320" name="quality">    
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create MP3 File">
                </form> 
            </td>
          </tr>
          </table>
          ';
          $videos .= '<li>'.$htmloutput.'</li>';
          break;
      }
      $i++;
    }

    $htmlBody .= <<<END
    <h3>Videos</h3>
    <ul>$videos</ul>
END;
  } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }
}

    //=================================================================================
    //END GOOGLE API INTEGRATION
    //=================================================================================

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow i must be tired. I figured it out.

Changed

$htmloutput .= '

To

$htmloutput = '

That fixed the problem i was having.

Thank You Guys!